# Join two table for insert data in database in Android

Tags: android, join, insert

I have two table(t1,t2) in Android,
t1 has a primary key  that it is foreign key for t2, I want to insert data to this tables, is  it necessary to join these two table? If yes, what is code for join these table?

I insert data in one of them like this:

```
public long insertQuote(String Quote,int Count1 ) 
        {
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(GoodName, Quote);
            initialValues.put(CartID, Count1);

            return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you sure that your input will not break the data integrity concept , you can leave them without joining .

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to join these two tables. Thus, you do not need these code.

Instead you need to make a transaction that contains two insertions in these two tables. At first, you need to insert into the first table, take the result of the insertion and insert this result as a foreign key into the second table. If a problem occurs on any of these steps, you need to roll back your changes. In this case your database will remain consistent.

Comment: when i insert data in a table with primarykey,this data doesn t put in foreign key in another table,what should i do for resolve this problem?

Comment: Of course not ) If you insert data in the first table you receive as a result id of a newly created entry. You should use this id to insert into the second table.